# How to use a colourmap to plot multiple plots on one graph and iterate over multiple different colourmaps

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib, colormap

I need to use a different colourmap for a range of different sensors. I'm planning to have these different colourmaps in a list that will be called upon in the loop. The individual colourmap for a sensor shows the range of temperatures the sensor was measured over.

So far I am struggling to implement this, I can specify a common colourmap in the loop, here 'Blues' but don't know how to loop over the different colourmaps

```
cmap = ['Blues', 'Purples', 'Blues', 'Greens', 'Oranges', 'Reds']
for j, n in enumerate(sensor_number):
    fig = plt.figure(str(n), figsize=[10,6])
    for k, T in enumerate(Temp):
        xs = np.linspace(t[0], t[-1], 1000)
        ys = model_funct(xs, *param[k][j])
        plt.plot(xs, ys, label="Standard Linear Model", color='k', linestyle='dashed
        cm = plt.cm.Blues(np.linspace(0.5, 0.8, len(Temp)))
        for i in range(len(Temp)):
            plt.scatter(t, R, s=0.5, label="Experimental Data", color=cm[i])
    #plt.savefig(dir + '\\Graphs\\' + str(n) + 'hj.png')
    plt.show()
```

where, t and R is my data

I have simplified and cut a lot of parts out of my code to show the problem, so the code might look a little unnecessary in places.

Also would a contour plot be better for this? Where a different contour is a different temperature

Answer (score 0):

Two example with the colormaps passed around/used as parameters as objects. One is following your approach with a separate fig/colormap for each sensor. But the data might be more understandable if you use one colormap for all, so I've shown how to share a colormap across all the sensors.

A practice that I have strong feelings about, especially for experimental/sensor data: it should always be stored and passed around with all its identifiers, metadata, however you want to think about it. Everything you could need to reconstruct where it came from. Build it in anywhere you can -- the datastructures that write sensor data to file, the filenames of images, tiny-text captions that you can crop off for publication but are always "really" there... anything. It is so easy to get scrambled and not too hard to set yourself up *once* so that you automatically label everything. Make the computer do the boring repetitive parts!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy.random as rand
import matplotlib.cm as cmap

# Dummy sensors
sensor_numbers = (213, 902, 34) 
cmaps = [cmap.summer, cmap.winter, cmap.inferno]
sensor_colors = zip(sensor_numbers, cmaps)

#dummy data for each sensor
#    I like keeping data "tied" to its ID in one structure;
#    dictionaries are flexible builtins
sensor_data = dict()
rand.seed(20240304)
N = 12
for n, c in sensor_colors:
    #making up (x, y, c) array data
    #pandas.DataFrame allows meaningful column names for more readable code
    sensor_data[n] = [rand.rand(N), rand.rand(N), n * rand.rand(N), c]  # different color ranges

for i in sensor_data: 
    fig, ax = plt.subplots( figsize=[3.5, 2])
    scatter = ax.scatter(sensor_data[i][0], sensor_data[i][1], 
                         s=20, c = sensor_data[i][2],
                         cmap=sensor_data[i][3])
    fig.colorbar(scatter, ax=ax)
    fig.suptitle("Data from sensor " + str(i))
    plt.savefig("multiple_colormaps_"+str(i)+".png")

# or! if you want to compare all the sensor's data,
# you actually want the *same* colormap for all of them
# find the limits of *all* the data
# before we can plot *any* data with the right color:
cmin, cmax = 10, 10
for i in sensor_data:
    cmin = min(min(sensor_data[i][2]), cmin)
    cmax = max(max(sensor_data[i][2]), cmax)
norm = plt.Normalize(cmin, cmax)
    
shapes = ('1', 8, '+')   # zip these IDs into sensor_data in place of the colormaps
for a, b in zip(sensor_numbers, shapes):
    sensor_data[a].append(b)
    
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[6, 4])
for i in sensor_data:
    scatter = ax.scatter(sensor_data[i][0], sensor_data[i][1], 
                          s=20, c = sensor_data[i][2],                             
                          label=i, marker=sensor_data[i][4], 
                          cmap=cmap.winter, norm=norm)
fig.colorbar(scatter, ax=ax)
ax.legend()
fig.suptitle("Experimental data")
plt.savefig("multiple_colormaps_shared.png")
```

From the first approach:

[image: scatter with greenyellow colorbar]

Shared colorbar:

[image: scatter with three markers one colorbar]

Comment: Sorry for the untimely reply, but thank you very much for the help! Each sensor was tested over a range of temperautres, which is where the colourmaping comes in and will use a different colourmap for each sensor. This is for an undergraduate project and as a physicist I am not very well versed in python but will try to reproduce your code with the data. For the sensor data c is the associated colourmapping, but how does ax.scatter associate its values to a cmap? Also would this extend to be based on temperature? Also if I could also ask about some janky code I have got to work -

Comment: For my code I have a list of colourmaps: cmaps = ['...', '...'] I call them using: cm = plt.get_cmap(cmaps[j])(np.linspace(0.25, 0.8, len(Temp))). The uniform colour of a scatter plot is then specified in the function by: color=cm[k] , where k specifies the index of the colourmapping to use (based on the index of the temperature in Temp). However I am now struggling to relate this to a colourbar, I am not sure what my mappable object should be in fig.colorbar(..., ax=ax1). I'd be very grateful for any help on this, sorry for asking for so much here aha

Comment: Busy today, but check out the documentation for `scatter`: the data you pass to the argument `c` will be plotted with color, and the mapping from data to a color is handled by the colormap you pass to the argument `cmap`.  And then once a plot has used a color*map*, matplotlib knows how to create a color*bar*. 

Happy to kibitz later --